# How to encode the "statement to be proven" for the existence of the cartesian product in FOL.

Tags: first-order-logic

One of the exercises I am trying to carry out is proving the existence of the cartesian product $S \times T$ for any two arbitrary sets $S$ and $T$. My question is **not** about how to construct this set (I feel fairly good-to-go with that).

I am trying to develop my ability to document what exactly it *is* that I am proving. I have two questions about the First Order Logic syntax of the overall *statement* I am trying to prove.

---

**Firstly**: is the overarching statement effectively something along the lines of: $$\forall S,T \  \exists \ N \varphi(N)$$ where $N$ is the "$S \times T$" and $\varphi(N)$ refers to the properties we associate with a cartesian product?

**Secondly**: when I am trying to demonstrate that this can be done for any arbitrary sets $x$ and $y$ (which would then generalize to *any two sets*), it seems like I am trying to prove an implication that looks something like (written in pseudo-FOL / English):

$$ x \ \text{and}\  y \ \text{are sets that can be constructed in our domain of discourse} \rightarrow x \times y \  \text{is a set that can be constructed in...etc }$$

I am a little uncertain about my proposed answer to the second question because I am unsure of how to encode the property "*can be constructed in our domain of discourse*" using FOL.

I've previously seen the following syntax to establish that "something exists": $\exists x (x=x)$.

So maybe the implication is better written as:

$$\exists x (x=x) \land \exists y (y=y) \rightarrow \exists x \times y ( x \times y = x \times y)$$

---

You can probably see that this question generalizes to the construction of any sets (not just the particular instance of the cartesian product set), so please feel free to speak more generally.

Looking forward to the input!
Thanks~

---

**Edit**:

Using the proper syntax provided by Mauro Allegranza below...

We set out to prove the following statement:

> $\forall S \forall T \exists C \forall z [z \in C \leftrightarrow z \in \mathcal P( \mathcal P (S \cup T)) \land \exists x \exists y (x \in S \land y \in T \land z=(x,y))].$

**Now**, the way I would approach this is the following:

---

**Consider two arbitrary sets $N$ and $M$.**

Prove the following:

$\exists C \forall z [z \in C \leftrightarrow z \in \mathcal P( \mathcal P (N \cup M)) \land \exists x \exists y (x \in N \land y \in M \land z=(x,y))]$

If I can prove the above statement for arbitrary sets $N$ and $M$, then I have proven it for any two sets.

---

My question is...what am I "doing" (in the context of FOL) when I assert - "**Consider two arbitrary sets $N$ and $M$.**" What is this statement? Does it have a truth value / interpretation? Is it an "English abbreviation" for some sort of FOL syntax?

Comment: 1st) Basically yes; you have to prove $\forall S \forall T \exists N [\forall x (x \in N \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))]$.

Comment: 2nd) Not necessary. In set theory quantifiers range over the domain of sets. Thus, to say $\forall x$ means "for every set...". You have already proved that some sets exist.

Comment: I don't know if it's a core part of your question, but I'd write something very different if I wanted to express that something was literally a standard construction in set theory of the cartesian product versus that something has "the properties we associate with a cartesian product". If you wanted to write this down in practice, you'd need to be intentional as to which you're aiming for.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA for your first response, I assume that follows from the axiom of comprehension? As for your second response, if you're willing, could you please add some additional details? I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: The consider $S$ and $T$ arbitrary... is the basis of [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): if we prove $\varphi(x)$ for an **arbitrary** variable $x$, then we can infer $\forall x \varphi(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I recognize that the "proof strategy" used to prove a universally quantified formula is to prove an instance of the formula for an arbitrary $x$. My confusion is specifically related to "the arbitrary variable $x$". From my basic understanding, to prove $\varphi(x)$, I first need to know that $x$ exists within my domain of discourse, don't I? It seems like I am taking a leap of faith when I say, "This arbitrary variable $x$ exists". I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA as an additional comment, I know that the idea of the "arbitrary element" is that we make no assumptions about the properties that it may, or may not, hold. But it seems like one of the assumptions we MUST make is that it exists in our domain of discourse. And that's where I am confused. Why do we get to make this assumption.

Comment: Variables range over elements of the domain. You have proved, through $\exists x (x=x)$, that something exists. In principle, we can have only the empty set, but it is enough: by Pair axiom we have that $\{ x,y \}$ exists and also $\{ x \}$, that with the empty set amount to $\{ \emptyset \}$ which is **not** empty. Thus, two sets exist. And by Power set axiom we have that $\mathcal P( \emptyset)$ exists, which is $\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$ that has two elements. And so on...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so if I were to operate within an axiomatic framework where I had not yet proven that "something exists", Universal Generalization would be effectively unavailable to me...at least until I could demonstrate that "something exists". Is that correct?

Comment: The standard convention regarding the semantics of FOL is that possible interpretations must have non-empty domains. This validates the inference $\forall x (x=x) \vdash \exists x (x=x)$. But there are also version of FOL allowing empty domains..

Comment: Having said that, Gen is **always** valid. If we have proved $\varphi(x)$ for $x$ arbitrary and assume that $\forall x \varphi$ is False, we have that its negation $\lnot \forall x \varphi \equiv \exists x \lnot \varphi$ is True. But this contradicts the fact that $\varphi$ holds for an arbitrary element of the domain. If in addition the domain is emepty, $\exists x \lnot \varphi$ is clearly false, and thus its negation $\forall x \varphi$ must be True.

Comment: Is the English interpretation of $\forall x (x=x) \vdash \exists x (x=x)$ effectively "a non-empty domain of discourse entails that there exists an element in the domain of discourse"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am going to write a separate post that largely centers on this topic (as the insights are probably better served as "Answers" rather than "Comments"). Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that: $S \times T = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in S \text {  and  } y \in T \}$.

Thus, a suitable formula defining it would be: $\exists C \forall z [z \in C \leftrightarrow \exists x \exists y (x \in S \land y \in T \land z=(x,y))]$.

But this is not enough, because in order to asserts that set $C$ exists we have to apply Separation.

In order to do this, we have to find a suitable set $A$ from which "separate" it.

If we adopt the common Kuratowski's encoding of $(x,y)$ as $\{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}$ we have, for $x \in S$ and $y \in T$, that:

> $\{ x \} \in \mathcal P(S)$ and $\{ x,y \} \in \mathcal P (S \cup T)$.

Thus, $(x,y) \in \mathcal P( \mathcal P (S \cup T))$.

In conclusion, the correct instance of the axiom will be:

> $\forall S \forall T \exists C \forall z [z \in C \leftrightarrow z \in \mathcal P( \mathcal P (S \cup T)) \land \exists x \exists y (x \in S \land y \in T \land z=(x,y))].$

The formula says that, for every *pair* of sets $S$ and $T$ their cartesian product $S \times T$ exists.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It gives me the ability to differently state my major source of confusion. I added something in an "Edit:" section above. I'd love for any insight you can offer. Cheers~